# Integrating Microsoft Azure AD Authentication library with an ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, azure-ad-msal

I would like to integrate the Microsoft Azure AD Authentication library into a pre-existing VB ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) project but I am failing with a CORS issue that occurs when the authentication challenge is made to Microsoft's login servers.

[Browser console error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HXuZ.jpg)

The code is mostly based on [this tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_-1fVDPhEY) but translated into VB. I was able to get this code working in a separate test project without this issue.

I have pasted in my full code below, where the point of failure is the `Page.Request.GetOwinContext.Authentication.Challenge()` method in the `AdLogin()` Sub, which should when called redirect to the Microsoft login authentication page. I have checked my Tenant ID, Application ID and authority string and I am confident they are correct. I have also tried multiple different redirect uris and implemented the UserCors method to no success either so I am at a bit of a loss. Any advice would be appreciated, thank you

**Auth Startup Code**

```
Public Sub ConfigureAuth(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)

    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = True
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 Or SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3

    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())

    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll)

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
        .ClientId = appID,
        .Authority = authority,
        .RedirectUri = redirectUri,
        .PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
        .TokenValidationParameters = New TokenValidationParameters() With {
            .ValidateIssuer = False
        },
        .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications() With {
            .AuthenticationFailed = AddressOf OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
            .AuthorizationCodeReceived = AddressOf OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync
        }
    })
    app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate)
End Sub
```

**Login Code**

```
    Private Sub AdLogin()

        Dim authProperties As AuthenticationProperties = New AuthenticationProperties()
        authProperties.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:14699/"
        authProperties.AllowRefresh = False
        authProperties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20)

        Page.Request.GetOwinContext.Authentication.Challenge(
            authProperties,
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

***Check the below steps to add the Azure AD Authentication into an existing VB App.***

- We have an option to add the Authentication Type while selecting the WebApp template.

[image]

- As you want to add Authentication into a pre-existing VB Application,
  add the `Microsoft Identity Platform`from the Connected Services.

[image]

[image]

- I have created a new Web App by selecting the Authentication Type as `Microsoft Identity Platform` to get the sample code.
- And I have Integrated the same into the pre-existing VB App.
- By default code does not have  `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll)`,I am able to run the app even after adding `UseCors`.

***My `StartupAuth.cs` file:***

```cs
Partial Public Class Startup
    Private Shared clientId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:ClientId")
    Private Shared aadInstance As String = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:AADInstance"))
    Private Shared tenantId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:TenantId")
    Private Shared postLogoutRedirectUri As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri")
    Private Shared authority As String = aadInstance & tenantId & "/v2.0"

    Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll)
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions() With {
            .ClientId = clientId,
            .Authority = authority,
            .PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications() With {
             .SecurityTokenValidated = Function(context)
                                           Dim name As String = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value
                                           context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name, String.Empty))
                                           Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                       End Function,
              .AuthenticationFailed = Function(context)
                                          Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                      End Function
              }
        })
       app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate)
    End Sub   
End Class
```

***Local Output:***
[image]

***Deployed App:***

[image]

Check my [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/harshithaveeramalla/vbadauth.git) which worked for me.

Use `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` token to clone the Repo.